# Can't use custom AuthenticationForm with LoginView

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

Trying to add Bootstrap CSS classes to the AuthenticationForm, but when adding authentication_form to the urls.py nothing changes? It finds the template and I can login, with custom user model.

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from user.forms import AuthForm
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('auth/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(
        authentication_form=AuthForm,
        template_name='user/login.html',), name='login'),
]
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.forms.widgets import PasswordInput, EmailInput


class AuthForm(AuthenticationForm):
    class Meta:
        widgets = {
            'username':forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class':'form-control form-control-sm'}),
            'password':forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control form-control-sm'}),
        }
# I have also tried
        username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class':'form-control form-control-sm'}))
        password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control form-control-sm'}))
```

I don't see what could be wrong? There is no error messages or anything and I can login, it's just that LoginView don't use the AuthForm at all. This is Django 2.1.7.

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to read the official documentation of django about [customizing authentication](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/).

First you can create a custom model for alter user model.

```sh
$ python manage.py startapp customuser
```

In customuser/models.py file create a new model called **User**

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin
)


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, full_name, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            full_name=full_name
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, full_name, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            full_name=full_name,
            password=password,
        )
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    full_name = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='full name',
        max_length=128
    )
    profile_image = models.ImageField(
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        upload_to='profile_images/')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['full_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_admin
```

In settings.py file update INSTALLED_APPS and change AUTH_USER_MODEL variable

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...,
    customuser,
]

...

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'customuser.User'
```

After this, you can already use the email to log in

Comment: I have a custom user model that takes email as username, I can also log in with the form, as the documentation says AuthenticationForm will take the USERNAME_FIELD. I have followed the documentation word by word as you probably also can see from "my" code. There is something I am missing, the only problem is that it will not use my AuthForm or rather authentication_form in urls.py. I don't get any errors either.

Comment: I just tried your code and it's perfect, please, you can include the content of your login.html file?.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the content of my template login.html, I have implemented your code in my test application and it works perfect.

In your app, add the **templates** folder, inside him create login.html file and add this code.

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% block content %}
    <form class="" action="{% url 'login' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <input type="submit" name="" value="Send">
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I appreciate your time and effort. I don't know what caused this, but I ended up just copying LoginView and AuthenticationForm and customize it directly under new names so it works now.